# Can anyone identify this part on a '96 Honda Prelude?

Tags: honda, part-identification, power-steering, sensor

I have an image of a particular part on my '96 Honda Prelude and I have no idea what it is. It's connected to the power steering and is some kind of sensor. Anyone have any insight?

[image]

Comment: And as father of the original poster on FB, I thank you very much as well! It is indeed in the hose, so I'm going with the Pressure Switch verdict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not positive from the picture but if that is screwed into the steering rack it's the Front sub-steering angle sensor.

If it's in a hose which seems more likely to me it's the power steering pressure switch.

Pictured below

[image]

[Link to Autozone site for part](http://www.autozone.com/autozone/parts/Power-Steering-Pressure-Switch/_/N-8oxqd?filterByKeyWord=SW1898&fromString=search&isSearchByPartNumber=true)

Power steering pressure switch reports power steering high pressures to the on-board computer When not replaced, engine may die during hard turns at idle and check engine light may illuminate

Comment: @cdhanson click the check mark to mark the answer correct. You can upvote too if you like, but not necessary.